# Python. List of Lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and I should find the sublist whose second element has the max value.

I implemented it as follows, but I would say it's a bit 'suboptimal' :-)

```
def max_value(inputlist):
    return max([sublist[-1] for sublist in inputlist])
```

and then

```
maxvalue = max_value(listofcounties)    
for result in listofcounties:
    if result[1] == maxvalue:
        return result[0]
```

There's a way to accomplish that in a more coincise form?

Thank you very much for any hint!
Bye
Fabio

Comment: `result[0]` will return the first element from the needed sublist, not the whole sublist

Comment: second element is `sublist[1]` not `sublist[-1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) accepts an optional `key` parameter; `max` compares the return value of the `key` function to determine which one is larger.

```
maxvalue = max(listofcounties, key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

---

```
>>> listofcounties = [['county1', 10], ['county2', 20], ['county3', 5]]
>>> max(listofcounties, key=lambda x: x[-1])  # by using `key`, max compares 10, 20, 5
['county2', 20]
```

Comment: Nice, but why `[-1]`, it's the second element (`[1]`), not the one before last, and if the sublists have 3 items?

Comment: Yeh sorry, i noticed now that i commented there too.

Comment: @Miguel, No problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another option (though not a very efficient one):**

Find all the sub-lists whose second element has the maximum value:

`[n for n in listofcounties if n[1] == max([k[1] for k in listofcounties])]`

Find the first sub-list whose second element has the maximum value:

`[n for n in listofcounties if n[1] == max([k[1] for k in listofcounties])][0]`

---

**Split it into two statements in order to improve efficiency:**

Find all the sub-lists whose second element has the maximum value:

`maxvalue = max([k[1] for k in listofcounties])`

`[n for n in listofcounties if n[1] == maxvalue]`

Find the first sub-list whose second element has the maximum value:

`maxvalue = max([k[1] for k in listofcounties])`

`[n for n in listofcounties if n[1] == maxvalue][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach using `sorted` function:

```
# the exemplary list was borrowed from @falsetru answer
listofcounties = [['county1', 10], ['county2', 20], ['county3', 5]]
max_sequence = sorted(listofcounties, key=lambda l: l[1], reverse=True)[0]

print(max_sequence)
```

The output:

```
['county2', 20]
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted